# How to draw a picturebox into a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am looking for some how-to information.  I want to custom draw a picturebox into an owner-drawn listbox.  I have been looking for examples on how to draw a control like a button or picturebox into a listbox but have not been able to find any.  All I can find are how to modify the colors of the text etc., nothing about drawing a usable control to be used.  Since this is new to me I really would like something pretty simple to follow.  Once I can see how its done I should be able to figure out the rest (maybe).

Basically what I am going to be doing is drawing a picturebox into the listbox, then make a call to add the picture, then add some text into each row of the listbox as its loading etc.

On a side note, lets say you draw a button onto the listbox (will have to do that also), will you be able to interact with the buttons on-click event etc.?  I want to make sure I have everything covered before I get too deep into this.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, something else?

Comment: See [control rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for rendering controls. But a PictureBox really displays just an image, so what else would you expect?? And no, rendering just colors pixels, no event model, unless you code for it.. Also: Why a ListBox? It is a poor control. Look into lowLayoutPanel..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that its winforms.  I will look into the Panel as mentioned but I chose a listbox because of some other interfaces that I have seen, I am trying to accomplish something similar but not that fancy.  I stumbled upon this interface and like how it looks [link]http://www.mediahuman.com/img/youtube-downloader/thumbnail-win.png

Comment: You can try to do that with a ListView, but UserControls in a FlowLayoutPanel is the simpler way..

Comment: Still a bit confused.  Okay, I am going to try the FlowLayoutPanel to add the controls that I want to appear.  Am I still going to use a listbox or a listview to make the panels appear for each row?  I have never done anything like this before, hope you can understand my confusion.  With the link I pasted above I am trying to get the same layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WPF you can use UserControls, which can also display multiple elements (eg. an Image + Text) and handle them properly.

If you are using WinForms you should be able to just add the element by writing `listbox.Items.Add(yourNewPictureBox)`. Create a new PictureBox by using `PictureBox newPB = new PictureBox()` and assign values like source or size.

Comment: Ian, are you referring to me?  I didn't down vote anything at all.  After reading the comments posted I had to start thinking in a different way since this is way too advanced for me to accomplish as a hobby programmer.

Comment: No I didn't mean you :) I meant the person that downvoted my answer without supplying a reason.